# How to adapt responsive a horizontal line of pointer

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am currently attempting to implement a horizontal pointer in a read/guide line mode. However, during testing on responsive devices, it does not extend fully across the width of the screen. Such as, on tablet and phone.

Could someone please advise on how to ensure that the horizontal pointer spans the entire width of the screen on responsive devices?

Thank you in advance!

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  const x = window.innerWidth;
  const y = e.pageY - window.pageYOffset;

  const follower = document.querySelector(".follower");
  follower.style.transform = `translate3d(${x}px, ${y}px, 0)`;
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#content {
  height: 2048px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#status {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.follower {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  top: 0%;
  left: -100%;
  transition: transform 0s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="follower"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Not sure what the point of translating this on the x-axis is supposed to be here in the first place. Why not just make this `\`translate3d(0, ${y}px, 0)\``, and `left: 0` for the initial position, to begin with ...? (The result of the rendered snippet here already appears to behave "better", as soon as I make that change.)

Comment: I guess you simply have to set `html.body{height; 100%, width: 100%}`. 

Comment: @CBroe I did it as you suggested, and the result is excellent. It seems like `translate3d(${x}px, ${y}px, 0)` is causing the x-coordinate to change along with the `left: -100%` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the point of translating this on the x-axis is supposed to be here in the first place.

Make this `translate3d(0, ${y}px, 0)`, and `left: 0` for the initial position, and it should work as intended.

(Using `window.innerWidth` often causes issues because of how the scrollbar width influences the result.)

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job:

**JS:**

```js
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      const x = window.innerWidth;
      const y = e.pageY - window.pageYOffset;

      const follower = document.querySelector(".follower");
      follower.style.transform = `translateY(${y}px)`;
    });
```

**CSS:**

```css
.follower {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  top: 0%;
  transition: transform 0s ease-in-out;
}
```